# Converting multi-parameter function to point-free style using Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Using [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/), I am trying to convert a fairly large function into a point-free, both for educational and stylistic reasons.

The function takes 4 arguments, an ES6 **map**, a **domainModel** function that takes an object and returns an object, a **key** property to identify what is being set on the map, and a **json** property that is set on the map after being invoked by **domainModel.**

```
const setNewDomainModelOnMap = curry((map, domainModel, key, json) => map.set(key, domainModel(json)));
```

Right now, I've curried the function for some functional goodness, but I'd like to work with a parameter free version if possible. I've successfully gone point-free style on functions with less parameters, can't quite figure out the right angle to approach this one.

Comment: I don't see any good way to do this.  Whatever point-free solution we created would probably be much less clear than the one you have there.  Is there any compelling reason to make it points-free?

Comment: You might consider that your function is impure before worrying about tacit definition – `map` is mutated if you're using ES6 Map instead of (eg) Immutable.Map

Comment: @ScottSauyet - probably, but I've been having a grand time learning Ramda trying to convert my application into point-free style... forces me to try using as much of the API as possible!

Comment: @naomik - backstory here is that MobX embraces mutable maps for handling state. Little bit of mutability is still okay with me

Comment: @user1787531 you talk about functional programming in very qualitative ways: *"stylistic"*, *"currying for functional goodness"* and *"little bit of mutability is OK"* – I fear you're missing a firm foundation which allows you to understand these concepts in a more concrete way. A specific discussion about mutability is way beyond the scope of this comment section, but I do recommend you spend more time with the basics before worrying about some of the topics presented in your question.

Comment: for sure, definitely recognize that my knowledge of functional programming is limited at best... my preferred learning strategy is to know just enough to be dangerous, expose myself to some interesting patterns, and then come back around a few weeks later with some solid grounding and theory to guide me, rewriting most of the code in the process... ymmv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**specializing functions**

The whole point of currying is that it allows you to specialize the function with each parameter that is bound. This allows us to write *generic* functions that can be specialized in a variety of ways

```js
const mult = x => y => x * y
const double = mult (2)
const triple = mult (3)
const negate = mult (-1)

console.log(double(5)) // 10
console.log(triple(5)) // 15
console.log(negate(5)) // -5
```

You have a function called `setNewDomainModelOnMap` which has a very specialized *name* but the function itself is extremely specific – there is nothing generic about it.

What if you wrote a *generic* function that could instead be specialized based on the arguments you give it?

```
// maybe something liek this would be better
const myfunc = set (someKey, someValue)
const updatedMap = myFunc (oldMap)
```

---

**Lateral thinking**

How about just `set` ?

The *nature* of your function is setting a value on a map – the fact that the value is augmented by some function `domainModel` doesn't mean that it has to be a parameter of your set function

```
const set = curry((key, value, map) =>
  map.set(key, value)
)

set(someKey, domainModel(json), someMap)
// => Map { ... }
```

And no, you can't remove any more points without your function turning into a disaster of nested `compose` calls – especially because you are wrapping a method (`map.set`) which would make preserving context much more complicated.

---

**Ramda agrees this is useful**

Ramda actually has it's own [set](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#set) function which operates on a Lens, some value, and some object.

```
var xLens = R.lensProp('x');

R.set(xLens, 4, {x: 1, y: 2});  //=> {x: 4, y: 2}
R.set(xLens, 8, {x: 1, y: 2});  //=> {x: 8, y: 2}
```

In light of this, you might want to name your function `mapSet` if you're ever worried about a naming conflict

Comment: Nice deconstruction naomik! If the problem is with the wrapped method call, could you do something like this to make it more composable? const mapSet = invoke(2, "set")...

Comment: it's no less composable in the way it's defined, but sure, you could use `R.invoker` for the same definition. I think it hurts readability and disguises some intent, but that's a personal opinion.

Comment: @user1787531 I made an edit to the beginning of the post that might help with your understanding of currying

Comment: thx for the heads up, just re-read, that is a very grokable definition of currying for my brain... just to confirm something that I've come across in the past day... compose plays very nicely with a chain of functions that have 1 parameter left unbound... currying can help turn multi-parameter functions into functions with 1 parameter left unbound... reasonable statements?

Comment: @user1787531 it's not about the number of unbound parameters. composition works best with unary functions, and all curried functions are unary functions (or sequences of unary functions). consider [repl: GjS9](https://repl.it/GjS9/1) – currying is about abstraction over arity; we have no idea when a function is "complete" because another function could be the valid result of a computation of another function. and if that's the case, that function could validly compute another function, and so on.

Comment: (cont'd) on the other hand, composing is about sequencing unary functions, regardless of any unbound params. you shouldn't really be thinking about number of args at all when you're dealing with a curried function. Just know it takes one argument now, and there is some return value. That return value could be anything, including another function – so yes, the concepts harmonize with one another but not in any sort of rigid way.